# Circumvent disabling android keyboard when a physical keyboard is plugged in

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

Using a card reader for a POS system that will be hooked into an android device. It seems to disable the android software keyboard while it is plugged in.

Is there a way to define whether or not to disable/enable the android keyboard per control or a way to circumvent the android soft keyboard being disabled?

Thanks,

W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))

                .showSoftInput(editText, 0);`

the above forces the soft keyboard to be visible. good luck

Comment: Should I put this in the onCreate of the activity?

Comment: yes, that would be a good place to put it, you need to look at what variables `showSoftInput` can take, it may be an overloaded method and can take a variety of variables

Comment: it may be a hardware control of the card reader, or a service that card reader's app runs that overrides your app settings, you may need to consult the card reader manufacturer. you can also try forcing the keyboard up in the androidmanifest for that activity

Comment: That's what I was thinking as your suggestion seems to be the answer to many of the questions surrounding this. I'm a little new to Android so pardon the next question but how can I go about forcing the keyboard up in the manifest?

Comment: Got it - android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible". I'll try this and let you know. Thanks for your help.